# rake db:reset ignores changes to migration

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, git, ruby-on-rails-4, migration

I have a migration that specifies a mySQL column size:

```
class CreateEntities < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :entities do |t|
      ...
      t.string  :telephone, limit: 50
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

Originally, this limit was `20`.

I can't seem to get this new limit to be applied to the database.

I have tried:

```
> rake db:reset
```

also

```
> rake db:drop
> rake db:setup
```

The old value persists.

I've also deleted the `schema.rb` file, but when it is recreated, it still includes the old value:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20140718164541) do

    create_table "entities", force: true do |t|
      ...
      t.string   "telephone",     limit: 20
      ...
    end
```

If it matters, I'm using Git.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rake db:reset` does not rerun your migrations. It clears the database, loads the schema and then sets up any seeds.  To change the limit on a column that already exists you should create a new migration that changes the column:

```
class ChangeEntitiesTelephoneLimit < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_column :entities, :telephone, :string, limit: 50
  end
end
```

If you really want to re-use the same migration, drop and re-create the database and then run the migrations:

```
rake db:drop
rake db:create
rake db:migrate
```

Comment: If the migration is one of the most recent migrations, you can also do `rake db:rollback STEP=N` to roll back `N` migrations. Then make your changes and rerun the migrations.